# ConcurrentThrottledList - Will this implementation be thread safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I want a thread safe list with a max item count, will the following implementation correctly provide this?

```
public class ConcurrentThrottledList<T>
{
    private readonly List<T>  items = new List<T>();
    private readonly int maxItems;
    private object _lock = new object();

    public ConcurrentThrottledList(int maxItems)
    {
        this.maxItems = maxItems;
    }

    public bool TryAdd(T item)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (items.Count < maxItems)
            {
                items.Add(item);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool TryRemove(T item)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return items.Remove(item);
        }
    }

    public bool IsFull { get { lock (_lock) { return items.Count >= maxItems; } } }

    public T[] Items { get { lock(_lock) { return items.ToArray(); } } }
}
```

Comment: I really can't see anything to improve.

Comment: Thanks everyone, all your comments are well received. The input is much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to expose `Count` similarly if is `IsFull` is useful. For example in a client/server application to show the clients the (most up-to-date available) number elements in some lists  and not just if they are full or not. Currently `.Items.Length` would cause memory waste.

Answer (score 5):

@ChrisW made valuable comments, I'll add mine:

#### Well done:

- I like that private fields are all<sup>1</sup> `readonly`, this makes intent explicit, which works towards greater maintainability.
- I like that the class is highly cohesive and focused, this works towards greater readability, maintainability and extensibility.

#### Nitpicks:

- I don't see why `_lock` gets an underscore and `items` and `maxItems` don't; being consistent with the underscore prefix for private fields would mootinate the `this` qualifier in the constructor.
- `Items` could be called `ToArray`, making it more consistent with the framework's lingo, and more representative of its semantics.
- `TryAdd` and `TryRemove` both look like they were named after [the `TryParse` pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505391/is-there-a-name-for-this-pattern); a developper looking at the API would then also be expecting an `Add` and a `Remove` method:

  - `Add` would add the specified item, throw an exception if it can't, and return `void`.
  - `TryAdd` would add the specified item, return `true` if successful and `false` otherwise.
  - `Remove` would remove the specified item, throw an exception if it can't, and return `void`.
  - `TryRemove` would remove the specified item, return `true` if successful and `false` otherwise.

**However**, [`List<T>.Remove()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx) is already taking care of returning `false` if the specified item cannot be removed - throwing an exception in that case would be utter nonsense. Therefore, I'll second @ChrisW in saying that `TryRemove` should be simply called `Remove`.

I agree with `TryAdd` being called as such, because I would seriously expect an `Add` method to return `void`, so I'd *consider* also having an `Add` method that throws some `CapacityExceededException` (or whatever is more appropriate) when it can't add the specified item.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I would be led to believe `_lock` could also be made `readonly`, but I don't work with enough multithreaded code to know whether that would/could impact anything.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

> will the following implementation correctly provide this?

Yes, it would appear so.

Minor comments:

- TryRemove could be called Remove (because List.Remove is called Remove).
- IsFull may not be useful (because it may be obsoleted by a subsequent Remove by another thread, before this thread is able to act on the IsFull return value)
- Do you want to be able to remove any element? If not, if you only want to remove the first or last element, then ConcurrentQueue or ConcurrentStack might be better than List (in which case only your TryAdd method would need your own explicit lock).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the existing answers:

1. I concur that `IsFull` is probably not all that useful.
2. `_lock` should be `readonly`
3. Your class is called `ConcurrentThrottledList` but you don't implement any of the collection interfaces. If you want to make it more useful consider implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, `ICollection<T>` and possibly `IList<T>`.